# Prestashop 8.1 - Warning that some variable is missing in 'smarty' despite no changes to the controller

Tags: php, xampp, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

- Prestashop 8.1
- PHP 8.1.23
- Windows 10

When making changes to the .tpl files after restarting xampp in the
the basic template on the index page, this message appears

```
Warning:  Undefined array key "count" in C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop_8.1\var\cache\dev\smarty\compile\combat\fa\6c\c3\fa6cc378d2942c8857b89d6bca728048c0caeedd_2.module.ps_featuredproductsviewstemplateshookps_featuredproducts.tpl.php on line 34



Warning:  Attempt to read property "value" on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop_8.1\var\cache\dev\smarty\compile\combat\fa\6c\c3\fa6cc378d2942c8857b89d6bca728048c0caeedd_2.module.ps_featuredproductsviewstemplateshookps_featuredproducts.tpl.php on line 34
```

It says that some variable is missing in **ps_featuredproducts.tpl** despite the absence of any changes in the controller itself with the same name **ps_featuredproducts.php** in the modules/ folder.

By the way, let me ask one more thing:
Do you know how in the basic template to the products page, where there are filters on the left side, I can add products that are on promotion? I tried to add it programmatically to the model **ps_specials.php** I added a hook to which I can mount it:

```
public function install()
    {
        $this->_clearCache('*');

        Configuration::updateValue('BLOCKSPECIALS_SPECIALS_NBR', 8);

        return parent::install()
            && $this->registerHook('actionProductAdd')
            ...
            && $this->registerHook('displayLeftColumn');
    }
```

template is themes/myNewTheme/templates/layouts/layout-both-columns

```
{hook h="displayLeftColumn"}.
```

By the way in the configuration file in themes/myNewTheme/config/theme.yml
says that the products and filters page uses **layout-left-column** and yet the whole thing is displayed in a different template :/.
PrestaShop 8.1 is terribly confusing :/.

Comment: Turn off your cache system in Prestashop: `Advanced settings -> Performance -> Template-compilation: Force compilation + Cache: No` in this way you will get an error pointing you more in the right way. The error's listed are from the module ps_featuredproducts

Comment: @Crezzur This mode is on all the time to always see changes